# knife/chef - how to capture command line argument and pass to a chef recipe

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

Is there a way to capture a command line argument and pass to a chef recipe? 
What I'm trying to do is to automate populating hostname to various places. One being in `/etc/sysconfig/network` DOMAIN field.

So if the command to start up a server is

```
knife ec2 server create -Z us-east-1c --image ami-fd375894 -E stage -d fedora17 -f c1.medium -i ~/.ssh/myKey -r "role[myserver]" -G myGroup -x ec2-user -T Name=myserverName -N myserverName.001 --ephemeral /dev/sdc=ephemeral0
```

I want to capture "myserverName" and pass that to various recipes which may need it to construct FQDN when bootstrapping.

This is not through JSON option, but straight from command line.

Comment: No, you can't. JSON is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

use a recipe which sets the hostname for the machine based on `Chef::Config[:node_name]`, since you set this value by the option `--name` on your command line.